# Is there any way to expose WCF methods and be able to invoke them like an asmx?

Tags: wcf, web-services, asmx

Is there any way to expose WCF methods and be able to invoke them like on an asmx file?

For example:
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx

In the above link you can select the different operations and can invoke them in the browser, is there any way to replicate that with a WCF service .svc file on an IIS server?

Answer (score 1):

Not really; you can use the WcfTestClient - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx - to test the methods, but there's no built-in "auto-invoker" for WCF.

Comment: I see that's a shame because it's such a useful tool to see if your methods are working correctly. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

The better way to see if your methods are working correctly is to create unit tests to call them. That way, you can see if your methods *continue* to work.